# Summing-if minutes shown as strings

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I have a range of times in minutes displayed as strings "30", "33" etc, which I will need to sum to display as the total number of minutes. Plus a value will need to be summed only if a condition is true - hence I will need to use SUMIF if I were in an Excel worksheet proper.

Is there a quick build-in function for summing stringed minutes (ideally a sumif variant) without using extensive VBA manipulations?

Note: I cannot append another column and convert those values to Time - it will have to be done in a single 'summing' cell.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your minutes are just stored as text, you can use a `SUMPRODUCT()` :

[image]

`=SUMPRODUCT((Ciriteria_range="Criteria")*Minutes_range*1)`